# Trying to understand asm interrupts, specifically 16h func 01H

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt, bios, dosbox

THIS IS FOR HOMEWORK, I don't expect you to resolve my problem, just need some understanding...

I have to work with ASM and C in a dosbox. My first problem is I don't really understand how to use bios interrupts (any good tutorial with code samples would be really appreciated), ok, I get there's interrupts, and each one has its own functions and parameters...

Anyway I've tried...What I need to do is, theoretically, simple, I just need to get a character from keyboard and if it is a 1 or 0 key, count it, if I have five keystrokes of key 1, I switch on the speaker, if the speaker is on and I have three 0 keys, the speaker is turned off, and also it can be turned off if mouse moves to the right...

I have it almost done, my problem is getting the returned byte from an interrupt and check it.

To get the char I use function 01H from INT 16H, that's why I don't want the asm block to wait until a new char came up, the problem is I can't undertand how to get the ZERO FLAG that tells me if a new char has arrived and if so, get it and remove it from the keyboard buffer.

Here's is my loop:

```
// Loop
for(;;) {
        initTimer();

        if (key == ESC) break; // If ESC is pressed...

        if (mouseExist == TRUE) currentX = getMouseX(); // Mouse X position

        /* In that block I wait for the user input, it works...
        asm {
            mov AH, 08H  
            int 21H     // DOS-API
            mov key, AL

        }
        */
            // Block I don't get...UPDATED
        asm {
            mov ah, 01H
            int 16h
                    jz not_set // If zero flag is 1, jump to not_set, else
            mov key, al // Getting key
                    mov ah, 04H  // reset buffer
                    int 16H

        }
            not_set:
            // Count ones
        if (key == ONE && countOnes < MAX_ONES) {
            countOnes++;
            resetBuffer(); // Reset keyboard buffer (NOT WORKING)...
        }
        // Count 0s
        else if (key == ZERO && isPlaying == TRUE) countZeros++;

        // If I have enought zeros OR speaker is on AND mouse have been moved to            
            // the right 
        if (countZeros == MAX_ZERO || (initX < currentX && isPlaying == TRUE)) {
            stop(); // Stop speaker...It works...
            // Restore counters
            countOnes = 0;
            countZeros = 0;
            checkMouse(); // Reset Mouse...Works...
            showMouse(); // Works
            initX = getMouseX();
                currentX = initX;
            isPlaying = FALSE;
        } else if (countOnes == MAX_ONES) { // I have the ones
            isPlaying = TRUE;
            play(); // Turn on the speaker.
        }
            key = '\0';
           // I have also try to reset buffer here...No luck...
           //resetBuffer()
    }
```

Function ResetBuffer:

```
void resetBuffer() {
    asm {
        mov AH, 04H // Function reset
        int 16H
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you using `Turbo C` ?

Comment: Yes I do, with dosbox...

Comment: I believe you might need to redirect `INT 16H` function `01H` and accordingly need to handle internal queue for buffered input. In this way you might be able to simultaneously check for both mouse movement as well as keystrokes

Answer (score 1):

You can push the flags, then pop them into a register to check the corresponding bit:

```
unsigned short flags;
asm {
    mov ah, 04h
    int 16h
    pushf
    pop ax
    mov flags, ax
}
if (flags & 0x40) {
    // zero flag is set
}
```

You could also directly check the flag in assembly:

```
    mov ah, 04h
    int 16h
    jz not_set
    // here, if zero flag was set
not_set:
```

The exact syntax of labels depends on your compiler.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, I know now how to get zero_flag and that my short need to be unsigned. I have change the block within the loop to use jnz but now it says: Undefined label 'not_set', don't know why...It is declared, I think...I've updated the post...

Comment: I haven't used Turbo C for some 20 years, so I cannot check the exact syntax to get labels working in inline assembly - but you could use the first option in my answer (`pushf`/`pop ax`) to get it done without the labels.