# Assembly 16h BIOS call not working

Tags: c, assembly, x86, keyboard, bios

```
char getchar() {
    char a;
    __asm {
            int 16h
            mov [a], AL
    }
    return a;
}
```

I tried to get user input from the keyboard but instead of waiting for keypress, it returns wierd characters without pressing any key on the keyboard.

Comment: It what environment are you running this? (Under Linux/under Windows/booting your own custom bootloader on bare metal/etc)

Comment: You must zero `AH` first to select the function.

Comment: My own bootloader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to understand asm interrupts, specifically 16h func 01H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686770/trying-to-understand-asm-interrupts-specifically-16h-func-01h)

Comment: Most interrupts require that you specify which operation you are attempting to perform.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_16H) for example.

Comment: Also in what way is that _nasm_?

Comment: I mistakenly put in nasm iinstead of watcom. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_16H#List_of_services_of_the_INT_16_h), 16H interrupt has several services and you have to select one of them using `ah` register.

function code for reading key press is `0` so you have to `xor ah, ah`(set ah to zero) before `int 16h`.